# Function returns True instead of False over iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing some challenges on edabit and I came across a problem with my output. So i have to Create a function that takes in an array (slot machine outcome) and returns true if all elements in the array are identical, and false otherwise. The array will contain 4 elements. Can someone explain why my code isn't working the right way.

I have tried with other inputs and it's working fine.

```
   'use strict';

   function array_Validator(e1,e2,e3,e4)
   {
       let m_Array=[e1,e2,e3,e4];
       for(let i=0;i<m_Array.length-1;i++)
       {
           for(let x=i;x<m_Array.length-1;x++)
           {
               if(m_Array[i]!==m_Array[x+1])
               {
                   return false;
               }
               else
               return true;
           }
       }
   }


  let u_Result=array_Validator("SS","SS","Ss","Ss");

   console.log(u_Result);
```

So when I input Ss it shoes true instead of false.

Comment: .every() would make more sense and not sure why you check things multiple times.

Comment: Note the first iteration of **inner loop**. You have a **return** there. So the function will always finish on the first iteration of the inner loop. Why `true` for your input data? Because for `x = i = 0` the expression `m_array[i] !== m_Array[x+1]` evaluates to `m_array[0] !== m_Array[1]` that results in `"SS" !== "SS"`. That last expression is `false` so `else` is taken and a `true` is returned.

Comment: Thnx !! I got it.

Comment: `const array_Validator = (...vals) => vals.every(v => v === vals[0])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `return true` to the end of the function and you could use a single loop and check the first element with each others.

```js
'use strict';

function array_Validator(e1, e2, e3, e4) {
    let m_Array = [e1, e2, e3, e4];
    for (let i = 1; i < m_Array.length; i++) {
        if (m_Array[0] !== m_Array[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}


let u_Result = array_Validator("SS", "SS", "SS", "Ss");

console.log(u_Result);
```

Comment: Thnx !! Helped Alot.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Rest Parameters ...args

```
function array_Validator(...args) {
    for (let i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (args[0] !== args[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
let u_Result = array_Validator("SS","SS","Ss","Ss");
console.log(u_Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the first iteration of **inner loop**: you have a **return** statement there on the `if` and the `else` blocks. So the function will always returns on the first iteration of the **inner loop**.

Why the result is `true` for your input data `"SS","SS","Ss","Ss"`?

Because in the first iteration, for `x = i = 0`, the expression `m_array[i] !== m_Array[x+1]` evaluates to `m_array[0] !== m_Array[1]` and that results in `"SS" !== "SS"`. That last expression is then evaluated to `false` and the `else` block is taken returning the `true` value.

There is no need to use nested loops to check if all the elements on an `array` are equals. Now, you can use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for this situation.

## Example:

```js
function array_Validator(e1, e2, e3, e4)
{
    let m_Array = [e2, e3, e4];
    return m_Array.every(elem => elem === e1);
}    

console.log(array_Validator("SS","SS","Ss","Ss"));
console.log(array_Validator("SS","SS","SS","Ss"));
console.log(array_Validator("SS","SS","SS","SS"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968449/11178909

Answer provided, do not use a double for loop for this method first of all

Comment: ganth mrau o wah hilio da